# Godaddy first page load is very slow for very simple test page

Tags: performance, performance-testing, page-load-time

I created account with godaddy to test performance i created very simple asp.net mvc5 application where I'm using EF6 with MySQL, where i have only one table with two columns and 5 rows of data in it.

```
return View(db.TodoStatus.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList());
```

- I created very simple Model with just Id and Name properties
- Added just 5 rows of data to display
- There is no image on the page
- First page load takes 42 to 58 seconds to load.
- If i load same page just after first it takes 7-15 seconds
- After some delay like 15 minutes if i try to load same page again it takes 42 to 58 seconds.

I tried this from different locations on different time but same result.  I contacted their help lien they said to pay more and buy some enterprise package.

I want to know if there could be something wrong with my configurations or godaddy is a garbage hosting option.

Comment: If you use Elastic Cloud Compute (EC2) from Amazon Web Services, there will be much less black magic in the hosting provider, and you'll get great performance. That said, a static file server that calls "serverless" services like AWS Lambda will be optimal if you can retool...

Comment: I checked some other accounts, they are working much reasonable, the only difference i found that they are php based, does it mean godaddy is poor on windows server based hosting?

Comment: thanks, that could be helpful, in fact based on recommendation i selected godaddy, its too hard to move everything, before that i wanted to sure, if I'm doing any thing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use godaddy and they are very slow. Especially with their shared hosting platform. I wouldn't waste the time and money with them by upgrading to their enterprise package. Just move to good host such as Liquidweb.com or Inmotionhosting.com For example you can see how my site [https://utvgearhq.com](https://utvgearhq.com/) loads with Inmotion Hosting. It is very heavy with large graphics but still loads quick, especially to how it loaded before on Godaddy.